# How to set the start background of X

Tags: linux, xorg

When our linux system starts I would like to change the background of X to either a

- bitmap
- a solid colour (red)

but using only configuration files. We use a pretty stripped down version of a ubuntu linux (12.10, with lightdm), so there are no such things as right click on desktop, choose background. We would like to show this background while our application (which upon loading takes up the entire screen) loads.

How do I do this? What files do I need to change?

**EDIT** (to let the world know what is available): I basically have xsetroot, and the various Xsession files, xrandr, bitmap, and these very basic X utilities. But for example no mouse on the X gui (this is a touch screen application, requires no mouse or keyboard). I have an ssh shell, I can log in and modify the files, and I have a reset button to test the settings :) No Unity, no KDE, no Gnome, just plain lightdm.

Answer (score 0):

You give very little info on what you have available on your stripped-down Ubuntu.

If you had a full-fledged Ubuntu 12.10 with Unity, then the following command would return the image currently used as background,

```
  gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
```

and you would change it as follows:

```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/my_name/Pictures/my_picture.jpg
```

If this does not work, you will have to state which tools you have available.